# React: Fetching data from a nested array

Tags: ajax, reactjs, fetch, array.prototype.map

For May 4th, I'm trying to do a little star wars React app with [this](https://swapi.co/api/) REST API. I'm fetching the data from the [people](https://swapi.co/api/people/) URL and inside of it are a couple of nested arrays that link to different URL's that also return more JSON.

What I need to do is find a good way of grabbing the data from the nested arrays while mapping the people JSON.

So my apps HTML would end up looking like

```
// this would be something like `<p>{ data.name }</p>`
<p>Name: Luke Skywalker</p>
// data data more data

// the `FILMS` array comes from `data.films` which only holds URL's
<div>
  <p>Films</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>The Empire Strikes Back</p>
  <p>Revenge of the Sith</p>
  // return the rest of movies character was in
</div>
```

Currently, my idea is to turn `CharData` into a class and have multiple `fetch` calls inside of `componentDidMount` and have it set the state hopefully resulting in a single array on the `this.state` object. But this would need to happen for EACH individual movie and all I want is the title. Just seems like a lot going on to return a single value.

### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

// components
import CharContainer from './comp/charcontainer/CharContainer';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      starwarsChars: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // feel free to research what this code is doing.
    // At a high level we are calling an API to fetch some starwars data from the open web.
    // We then take that data and resolve it our state.
    fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people')
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ starwarsChars: data.results });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw new Error(err);
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1 className="Header">React Wars</h1>

        {/* Char Container */
        (this.state.starwarsChars.length > 0)
          ?
            <CharContainer charData={ this.state.starwarsChars } />
          :
            <h2>Fetching Character Information...</h2>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

### CharData.js

```
import React from 'react';

const CharData = props => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>

      {
        props.charData.map((char, ind) => {
          return (
            <div className='char-card-container__char-card-wrapper'>
              <div key={ind + Date.now()} className="char-card-container__char-card">

                <h2 className='mt-2'>{char.name}</h2>
                <p className='mt-2'><span className='char-card__char-info-label'>Gender:</span> {char.gender}</p>
                <p className='mt-2'><span className='char-card__char-info-label'>Birth Year:</span> {char.birth_year}</p>
                <p className='mt-2'><span className='char-card__char-info-label'>Eye Color:</span> {char.eye_color}</p>
                <p className='mt-2'><span className='char-card__char-info-label'>Hair Color:</span> {char.hair_color}</p>
                <p className='mt-2'><span className='char-card__char-info-label'>Height:</span> {char.height}</p>
                <p className='mt-2'><span className='char-card__char-info-label'>Weight:</span> {char.mass}</p>
                <p className='mt-2'><span className='char-card__char-info-label'>Skin Color:</span> {char.skin_color}</p>

                <div className='mt-2'>
                  <div>
                    <p className='char-card__char-info-label'>Films</p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    {
                      char.films.map(film => {
                        return (
                          <p>{film}</p>
                        )
                      })
                    }
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className='mt-2'>
                  <div>
                    <p className='char-card__char-info-label'>Specie</p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    {
                      char.species.map(specie => {
                        return (
                          <p>{specie}</p>
                        )
                      })
                    }
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className='mt-2'>
                  <div>
                    <p className='char-card__char-info-label'>StarShips</p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    {
                      char.starships.map(starship => {
                        return (
                          <p>{starship}</p>
                        )
                      })
                    }
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className='mt-2'>
                  <div>
                    <p className='char-card__char-info-label'>Vehicles</p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    {
                      char.vehicles.map(vehicle => {
                        return (
                          <p>{vehicle}</p>
                        )
                      })
                    }
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })
      }

    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default CharData;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rendering `<p>{film}</p>` you could render `<FilmContainer film={film} />` where `film` is a URL that you can fetch in a similar way that you do in the `App`.

You might end up with lots of those containers for different kinds of details. One way to tackle the duplication would be to use [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) approach.

```
class FetchContainer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      data: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.props.url)
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false, 
          data,
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw new Error(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children({
      loading: this.state.loading,
      data: this.state.data
    });
  }
}
```

Here's how this component can be used to show the film info in person's details:

```
{char.films.map(film => (
  <FetchContainer url={film}>
    {({ loading, data }) => loading ? (
      <p>Loading film...</p>
    ) : (
      <p>{data.title}</p>
    )}
  </FetchContainer>
))}
```

Comment: Yea that definitely sounds like a good solution. I've been trying to be conscious of time complexity in my apps both large and small. I'm not 100% sure how React renders components but in my mind, this looks like a nested loop correct? A `map` inside a `map` or am I wrong? Regardless, this is still a great answer thank you.

Comment: You are right, the initial render will take O(a*b) time, but I'm not sure how insightful this metric is. You can not avoid nested loops when you want to show lists of data with unknown number of elements. What you should focus on, after you implement your markup logic, is [reducing the number of unnecessary re-renders](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#shouldcomponentupdate-in-action) and using [list virtualization](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#virtualize-long-lists) to limit rendering to the current viewport.